# session bean interfaces differences and needs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans, ejb-3.0

I started to learn EJB 3.0 and I was wondering why EJB session needs an interface (local or remote) ?

What's the difference between these two interfaces ?

I have read a lot of articles about that but I am still confused.

Comment: The answer in the link will answer your question about local/remote interfaces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3809779/2588800 Also EJBs may have a `no interface view` besides the local/remote interfaces

Comment: I would like to add another question that deals very well with the issue: [What is local/remote and no-interface view in EJB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729905/what-is-local-remote-and-no-interface-view-in-ejb)