# Maven: getting NullPointerException when trying to insert into database

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I created a server side Maven project called **revison-ejb** and Maven client project **revison-ejb-client**.

Database table is already created but I get NullPointerException when trying to insert into t_player table.
Any help would be appreciated!

**revison-ejb**

Player.java

```
package edu.foot.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Player
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_player")

public class Player implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private int age;
    private String nom;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Player() {
        super();
    }

    public Player(int age, String nom) {
        super();
        this.age = age;
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return this.nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [id=" + id + ", age=" + age + ", nom=" + nom + "]";
    }

}
```

PlayerServiceRemote.java

```
    package edu.foot.interfaces;

import edu.foot.entities.Player;

public interface PlayerServiceRemote {

    void add(Player player);

    void update(Player player);

}
```

PlayerService

```
package edu.foot.interfaces.impl;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import edu.foot.entities.Player;
import edu.foot.interfaces.PlayerServiceRemote;

@Stateless
public class PlayerService implements PlayerServiceRemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void add(Player player) {
        em.persist(player);

    }

    public void update(Player player) {
        em.merge(player);

    }

}
```

**revison-ejb-client**

```
package edu.esprit.irt.Player;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import edu.foot.entities.Player;
import edu.foot.interfaces.PlayerServiceRemote;

public class AddPlayer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InitialContext ctx = null;
        PlayerServiceRemote proxy = null;
        String jndi = "revison-ejb/PlayerService!edu.foot.interfaces.PlayerServiceRemote";

        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            proxy = (PlayerServiceRemote) ctx.lookup(jndi);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Player p1 = new Player(10, "Dirar");

        proxy.add(p1);

    }

}
```

**the error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.esprit.irt.Player.AddPlayer.main(AddPlayer.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are invoking EJBs from outside of the container, you need to annotate your interface as

```
@Remote
public interface PlayerServiceRemote {
```

You can check information on  [when to use @Remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807662/ejbs-when-to-use-remote-and-or-local-interfaces)

Comment: Thank you, I already figured it out , half an hour ago after a whole day of searching.